# Where can I find the original derivation of Walter Ritz ballistic theory?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, resource-recommendations, charge, specific-reference

Where can I find the original derivation of [Walter Ritz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walther_Ritz) ballistic theory? I think it can be found most probably in his own book "Gesammelte werke Walter Ritz". Although there is an english version, I can find it nowhere in the internet. Also I can find a derivation in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ritz_ballistic_theory). But I need much more detail. Please provide a link to a lengthy (or original) derivation of ritz theory.

Answer (score 0):

An English translation is "Critical Researches on General Electrodynamics"
an online version is at http://www.shadetreephysics.com/crit/1908a.htm